# jQuery dialog not opening in load callback

Tags: jquery

Working with jQuery 1.12.4 and jQuery mobile 1.3.0

I am trying to load an external html into a div on the existing page and open it in a new dialog. What I have loads the content, and displays the dialog, but only if I click twice.  The first click is loading the content, but not launching the dialog until I click again.

I've done extensive searching but I can't tell why it won't do it all on the first click.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#returnLabel").click(function() {
    $("#ticketArea").load("URL", function() {
      $(this).dialog({
        position: {
          my: "center",
          at: "top"
        },
        width: "1120px",
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        modal: true,
        title: "Return Label",
        dialogClass: "ticket",
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Click target:

```
<li><a href="#" id="returnLabel">Return Label</a></li>
```

Target div:

```
<div id="ticketArea" data-enhance="false" style="display: none;"></div>
```

How can I get both the load and the dialog to trigger on the first click?

Answer (score 0):

You have `style="display: none;"` in the `$("#ticketArea")` markup...

Try:

```
//...
  $("#ticketArea").load("URL", function() {
      $(this).show().dialog({
        //..
```

Comment: This solution makes the div appear with the content, but doesn't load the dialog.

Comment: Removing the `display:none` and changing the dialog to come after and separate from the load inside the click function ended up working for me though. I wouldn't have thought about the `display:none` without your help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Removing the `style='display: none'` from the div and changing the script top the following worked for me:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#returnLabel").click(function() {
                $("#ticketArea").load("/sites/memberservices/omni/Site%20Assets/Custom%20Forms/Return%20Label2.html");
                $('#ticketArea').dialog({
                            position: {
                                my: "top",
                                at: "top"
                            },
                            width: "1120px",
                            resizable: false,
                            draggable: false,
                            modal: true,
                            title: "Return Label",
                            dialogClass: "ticket",
                        });
            });
        });
```